# How I can add a long code in $mail->Body

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

How I can add a long code , like this  in `$mail->Body

**My HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
  <title>Say hello to card</title>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style type="text/css">
  #outlook a { padding: 0; }
  .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; }
  .ExternalClass { width: 100%; }
  .ExternalClass * { line-height:100%; }
  body { margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
  table, td { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
  img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }
  p { display: block; margin: 13px 0; }
</style>
<style type="text/css">
  @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
    @-ms-viewport { width:320px; }
    @viewport { width:320px; }
  }
</style>

<style type="text/css">
  @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
    .mj-column-per-100 { width:100%!important; }
.mj-column-per-35 { width:35%!important; }
.mj-column-per-65 { width:65%!important; }
.mj-column-per-80 { width:80%!important; }
  }
</style>
</head>
<body style="background: #F2F2F2;">

  <div class="mj-container" style="background-color:#F2F2F2;"><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:10px 0px 20px 0px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#9B9B9B;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;line-height:24px;text-align:center;">Writing A Good Headline For Your Advertisement</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 20px 0px 20px;"><div class="mj-column-per-35 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;" align="left"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:500;line-height:24px;text-align:left;">// BR&AND</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="mj-column-per-65 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;" align="right"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;line-height:24px;text-align:right;"><a href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">HOME</a>   /   <a href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">SERVICE</a>   /   <a href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">THIRD</a></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 20px 0px 20px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:30px 40px 10px 40px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#5FA91D;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:32px;font-weight:300;line-height:40x;text-align:center;">Free Advertising For Your Online Business.</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:10px 20px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;"><p style="font-size:1px;margin:0px auto;border-top:3px solid #9B9B9B;width:30px;"></p></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px 20px 20px 20px;"><div class="mj-column-per-80 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;padding-top:10px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:500;line-height:24px;text-align:center;">A Right Media Mix Can Make The Difference.</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:url(http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/bg.jpg) top center / cover no-repeat;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:url(http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/bg.jpg) top center / cover no-repeat;" align="center" border="0" background="http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/bg.jpg"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;" align="center"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="width:600px;"><img alt="" title="" height="auto" src="http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/lineshadow.png" style="border:none;border-radius:0px;display:block;font-size:13px;outline:none;text-decoration:none;width:100%;height:auto;" width="600"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:50px 40px 0px 40px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:300;line-height:24px;text-align:center;">Marketers/advertisers usually focus their efforts on the people responsible for making the purchase. In many cases, this is an effective approach but in other cases it can make for a totally useless marketing campaign.</div></td></tr><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:100px;" align="center"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="border:none;border-radius:2px;color:#FFFFFF;cursor:auto;padding:15px 30px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#5FA91D"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;background:#5FA91D;color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;line-height:120%;text-transform:none;margin:0px;" target="_blank">CALL TO ACTION</a></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:50px 0px 0px 0px;">
      <div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;" align="center"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="width:600px;"><img alt="bottom border" title="" height="auto" src="http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/bottom.png" style="border:none;border-radius:0px;display:block;font-size:13px;outline:none;text-decoration:none;width:100%;height:auto;" width="600"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:10px 0px 20px 0px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#9B9B9B;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;line-height:24px;text-align:center;"><a href="#" style="color: #9B9B9B;">Unsubscribe</a> from this newsletter<br>52 Edison Court Suite 259 / East Aidabury / Cambodi<br>
            <a href="#" style="color: #9B9B9B; text-decoration:none;">Made by </a></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

More exactly like this.

**PHP CODE**

```
    <?php
            include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";

            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->setFrom('test@test.com');
            $mail->addAddress($email, $name);
            $mail->Subject = "Please verify email!";
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Body = "
                Please click on the link below:<br><br>
                <!doctype html>
                <html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><head>  <title>Say hello to card</title>  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><style type="text/css">  #outlook a { padding: 0; }  .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; }  .ExternalClass { width: 100%; }  .ExternalClass * { line-height:100%; }  body { margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }  table, td { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }  img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }  p { display: block; margin: 13px 0; }</style><style type="text/css">  @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {    @-ms-viewport { width:320px; }    @viewport { width:320px; }  }</style><style type="text/css">  @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {    .mj-column-per-100 { width:100%!important; }.mj-column-per-35 { width:35%!important; }.mj-column-per-65 { width:65%!important; }.mj-column-per-80 { width:80%!important; }  }</style></head><body style="background: #F2F2F2;">    <div class="mj-container" style="background-color:#F2F2F2;"><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:10px 0px 20px 0px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#9B9B9B;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;line-height:24px;text-align:center;">Writing A Good Headline For Your Advertisement</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 20px 0px 20px;"><div class="mj-column-per-35 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;" align="left"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:500;line-height:24px;text-align:left;">// BR&AND</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="mj-column-per-65 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;" align="right"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;line-height:24px;text-align:right;"><a href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">HOME</a>   /   <a href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">SERVICE</a>   /   <a href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">THIRD</a></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 20px 0px 20px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:30px 40px 10px 40px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#5FA91D;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:32px;font-weight:300;line-height:40x;text-align:center;">Free Advertising For Your Online Business.</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:10px 20px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;"><p style="font-size:1px;margin:0px auto;border-top:3px solid #9B9B9B;width:30px;"></p></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px 20px 20px 20px;"><div class="mj-column-per-80 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;padding-top:10px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:500;line-height:24px;text-align:center;">A Right Media Mix Can Make The Difference.</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:url(http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/bg.jpg) top center / cover no-repeat;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:url(http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/bg.jpg) top center / cover no-repeat;" align="center" border="0" background="http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/bg.jpg"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;" align="center"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="width:600px;"><img alt="" title="" height="auto" src="http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/lineshadow.png" style="border:none;border-radius:0px;display:block;font-size:13px;outline:none;text-decoration:none;width:100%;height:auto;" width="600"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:50px 40px 0px 40px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:300;line-height:24px;text-align:center;">Marketers/advertisers usually focus their efforts on the people responsible for making the purchase. In many cases, this is an effective approach but in other cases it can make for a totally useless marketing campaign.</div></td></tr><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:100px;" align="center"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="border:none;border-radius:2px;color:#FFFFFF;cursor:auto;padding:15px 30px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#5FA91D"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;background:#5FA91D;color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;line-height:120%;text-transform:none;margin:0px;" target="_blank">CALL TO ACTION</a></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:50px 0px 0px 0px;">   <div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;" align="center"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="width:600px;"><img alt="bottom border" title="" height="auto" src="http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/bottom.png" style="border:none;border-radius:0px;display:block;font-size:13px;outline:none;text-decoration:none;width:100%;height:auto;" width="600"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:10px 0px 20px 0px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#9B9B9B;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;line-height:24px;text-align:center;"><a href="#" style="color: #9B9B9B;">Unsubscribe</a> from this newsletter<br>52 Edison Court Suite 259 / East Aidabury / Cambodi<br>            <a href="#" style="color: #9B9B9B; text-decoration:none;">Made by </a></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></body></html>

                <a href='http://test/test/confirm.php?email=$email&token=$token'>Click Here</a>
            ";

            if ($mail->send())
                $msg = "You have been registered! Please verify your email!";
            else
                $msg = "Something wrong happened! Please try again!";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't use `"` unescaped in the body if you are enclosing the string in `"`, enclosing the string in `'` would work but you would need to take the variables out.

Comment: You have double quotes inside a double-quoted string. PHP doesn't know where the string ends.

Comment: As the others say, but most reliable way would be to use a “heredoc”. Look it up in PHP docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

```
$mail->Body = <<<BODY
    Please click on the link below:<br><br>
    <!doctype html>
    <html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><head>  <title>Say hello to card</title>  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><style type="text/css">  #outlook a { padding: 0; }  .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; }  .ExternalClass { width: 100%; }  .ExternalClass * { line-height:100%; }  body { margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }  table, td { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }  img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }  p { display: block; margin: 13px 0; }</style><style type="text/css">  @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {    @-ms-viewport { width:320px; }    @viewport { width:320px; }  }</style><style type="text/css">  @media only screen and (min-width:480px) {    .mj-column-per-100 { width:100%!important; }.mj-column-per-35 { width:35%!important; }.mj-column-per-65 { width:65%!important; }.mj-column-per-80 { width:80%!important; }  }</style></head><body style="background: #F2F2F2;">    <div class="mj-container" style="background-color:#F2F2F2;"><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:10px 0px 20px 0px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#9B9B9B;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;line-height:24px;text-align:center;">Writing A Good Headline For Your Advertisement</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 20px 0px 20px;"><div class="mj-column-per-35 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;" align="left"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;font-weight:500;line-height:24px;text-align:left;">// BR&AND</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="mj-column-per-65 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;" align="right"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;line-height:24px;text-align:right;"><a href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">HOME</a>   /   <a href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">SERVICE</a>   /   <a href="#" style="color: #000000; text-decoration: none;">THIRD</a></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:20px 20px 0px 20px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:30px 40px 10px 40px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#5FA91D;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:32px;font-weight:300;line-height:40x;text-align:center;">Free Advertising For Your Online Business.</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:10px 20px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;"><p style="font-size:1px;margin:0px auto;border-top:3px solid #9B9B9B;width:30px;"></p></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px 20px 20px 20px;"><div class="mj-column-per-80 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;padding-top:10px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:500;line-height:24px;text-align:center;">A Right Media Mix Can Make The Difference.</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:url(http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/bg.jpg) top center / cover no-repeat;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:url(http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/bg.jpg) top center / cover no-repeat;" align="center" border="0" background="http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/bg.jpg"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:0px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;" align="center"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="width:600px;"><img alt="" title="" height="auto" src="http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/lineshadow.png" style="border:none;border-radius:0px;display:block;font-size:13px;outline:none;text-decoration:none;width:100%;height:auto;" width="600"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:50px 40px 0px 40px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#000000;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:300;line-height:24px;text-align:center;">Marketers/advertisers usually focus their efforts on the people responsible for making the purchase. In many cases, this is an effective approach but in other cases it can make for a totally useless marketing campaign.</div></td></tr><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:100px;" align="center"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="border:none;border-radius:2px;color:#FFFFFF;cursor:auto;padding:15px 30px;" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#5FA91D"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;background:#5FA91D;color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;line-height:120%;text-transform:none;margin:0px;" target="_blank">CALL TO ACTION</a></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;background:#FFFFFF;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;background:#FFFFFF;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:50px 0px 0px 0px;">   <div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:0px;" align="center"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="width:600px;"><img alt="bottom border" title="" height="auto" src="http://nimus.de/share/tpl-card/bottom.png" style="border:none;border-radius:0px;display:block;font-size:13px;outline:none;text-decoration:none;width:100%;height:auto;" width="600"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;width:100%;" align="center" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:top;direction:ltr;font-size:0px;padding:10px 0px 20px 0px;"><div class="mj-column-per-100 outlook-group-fix" style="vertical-align:top;display:inline-block;direction:ltr;font-size:13px;text-align:left;width:100%;"><table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0"><tbody><tr><td style="word-wrap:break-word;font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;" align="center"><div style="cursor:auto;color:#9B9B9B;font-family:Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;line-height:24px;text-align:center;"><a href="#" style="color: #9B9B9B;">Unsubscribe</a> from this newsletter<br>52 Edison Court Suite 259 / East Aidabury / Cambodi<br>            <a href="#" style="color: #9B9B9B; text-decoration:none;">Made by </a></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></body></html>

    <a href='http://test/test/confirm.php?email=$email&token=$token'>Click Here</a>
BODY;
```